# SecurityPermission error when instantiating media player

Tags: c#, com, activex, javascript

I'm using a Class Library exporting a function via COM.
When calling this function from a JScript, it fails with the following error:

```
Error:  System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
Code:   8013150A
```

Here's the C# code of my library:

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("B40EFE10-FC1B-43A0-ADA1-C923935F3537")]
public class ExodusGadget
{
    private WindowsMediaPlayer wmp;

    public void Play(string file)
    {
        wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
        //wmp.URL = file;
        //wmp.controls.play();
    }
}
```

And I'm using this JScript code (running in Windows Scripting Host, i.e. without IE-related restrictions) to call it:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject('ExodusGadget.ExodusGadget');
obj.play('somefile.mp3');
```

Calling other methods in my class which do not instantiate windows media player work fine.
Thanks to microsofts unhelpful error messages I don't really have an idea what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was due to the project and thus the DLL being on a network drive which windows considers as untrusted. Moving it to a local HDD fixed the problem.